# File not found error even if the file is placed in specified ;path

Tags: java, java-7

My current directory has a file named "info". But I still get a File not found error when using new File("info");

My cwd is : C:\Users\sit\eclipse-workspace\Assignment%03\bin\info

```
 String rootPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
        String info_file = rootPath + "info";

        // Read the properties into the internal structure

        try {
          identity.load(new FileInputStream(info_file));
        } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

The error I get is:
C:\Users\sit\eclipse-workspace\Assignment%03\bin\info(The system cannot find the path specified)

But I already have that file named info in the specified path. Not sure why it's not finding

I am using Java 1.7 , Eclipse platform on windows

Comment: Is it really the case that your directory is `...\Assignment%203` and not `...\Assignment 3`?

Comment: In root path it's showing as Assignment%03.But My folder name is Assignment 3

Comment: That is not the correct way to use getResource at all.  Calling getPath() on a URL does not return a valid file name.  If `info` is in the same directory as your compiled classes, `getClass().getResourceAsStream("info")` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the project folder name from Assignment 3 to Assignment3 and it solved the problem